# Hebrew text appear as squares with question mark on whatsapp for web/chrome/macbook pro

Tags: macos, google-chrome, macbook-pro-retina, hebrew, whatsapp

I'm using WhatsApp on the web with my Chrome browser (I have a MacBook Pro). While the Hebrew text appears OK on the left and the input panels, the Hebrew characters on the main "chat panel" appear as squares with question marks inside.

[image: chat panel]

I tried reset, uninstall and install/update Chrome version, disabled all extensions, and changed the encoding setting to Auto or UTF-8, but nothing solved the issue. I also looked at the flag mentioned above but I didn't find it in the link posted with the answer. The App works perfectly with Safari!

Someone?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your browser font.
The font that you using not support Hebrew.

Chrome > Settings > Web Content > Customize font.. > "Then choose Arial Hebrew or other font that support Hebrew"

Comment: Hi Eitan, Thanks for your answer!
It Worked!!! :)
I do not know how this simple solution eluded all the people i asked for help (including whatsapp support and web Dev experts!!!).
actually, I fill kind of dumb I didn’t find it myself :)
thank you again!